# Azure Linux VM accessible only from our Sharepoint

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-virtual-machine

We're using Sharepoint Online (Office 365).  I would like to create a Linux VM on Azure to build an API that would only allow access from our Sharepoint sites through ajax requests.

Is there a way to restrict access to the Linux VM on Azure only from ajax requests from authenticated users on our Sharepoint site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, you could add an Inbound NSG rule to allow access from your Sharepoint site IP.

[image]

More information about Azure NSG, you could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg).